# I Can't Get the Dropdown Menu To Input Data Into this JS Salary Calculator

Tags: javascript, dropdown, calculator

https://codepen.io/boris-koyfman/pen/jOzGVJv

```
<body>

<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1">

<h1>Salary Calculator</h1>
  <label for="edu"><h2>Level of Education</h2></label>

<label for="item1" class="container">Asso
  <input type="checkbox" id="item1" value="2000" name="ckb" onclick='eduChkcontrol(0)'>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label for="item2" class="container">BA
  <input type="checkbox" id="item2" value="4000" name="ckb" onclick='eduChkcontrol(1)'>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<label for="item3" class="container">MA
  <input type="checkbox" id="item3" value="6000" name="ckb" onclick='eduChkcontrol(2)'>
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
  </form>
  
  <form method="post" name="form2" id="form2">
     <label for="edu"><h2>Have you worked as a paramedic?</h2></label>

    <label for="item4" class="container">Yes
      <input type="checkbox" id="item4" value="5400" name="paraCkb" onclick='paramedicChkcontrol(0)'>
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>

    <label for="item5" class="container">No
      <input type="checkbox" id="item5" value="0" name="paraCkb" onclick='paramedicChkcontrol(1)'>
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
  </form>
  
   <form method="post" name="form3" id="form3">
     <label for="edu"><h2>Are you bilingual?</h2></label>

    <label for="item6" class="container">Yes
      <input type="checkbox" id="item6" value="900" name="bilingCkb" onclick='bilingChkcontrol(0)'>
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>

    <label for="item7" class="container">No
      <input type="checkbox" id="item7" value="0" name="bilingCkb" onclick='bilingChkcontrol(1)'>
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
  </form>
  
  <form method="post" name="form4" id="form4">
    <label for="edu"><h2>Ambulance - $25/shift</h2></label>
    <select name="ambulance" id="ambulance">
      <option id="item8" name="item8" value="0">0</option>
      <option id="item9" name="item8" value="250">10</option>
      <option id="item10" name="item8" value="500" >20</option>
    </select>    
  </form>

  <form>
  <p id="total" class="priceInfo"></p>
   
  <div class= "buttonDiv">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Calculate Total" id="calcButton">
  </div>

  </form>

</body>
```

```
/* The container */
.container 
{
  
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;

}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input 
{
  
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a red background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark 
{
  background-color: red;
  
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after 
{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after 
{
  display: block;
  
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

form
{
    border:5px solid #148BA6;
  border-radius:20px;
  width: 50%;
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
  background-color:#F2E394;
}

label
{
    margin-left: 20px;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size: 14px;
 
}

h1
{
    text-align:center;
  font-family:arial;
}

body
{
  background-color:#BDE3F2;
}
.button {
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family:arial;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #8C4130;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.button:hover
{
  background-color:#8C4130;
}


.buttonDiv, .priceInfo
{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
}
.priceInfo
{
    text-align:center;
  font-family:arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```
//limit to 1 choice - education
function eduChkcontrol(j) {
var total=0;
for(var i=0; i < document.form1.ckb.length; i++){
if(document.form1.ckb[i].checked){
total =total +1;}
if(total > 1){
alert("Please Select only one") 
document.form1.ckb[j].checked = false ;
return false;}}}

//limit to 1 choice - paramedic
function paramedicChkcontrol(j) {
var total=0;
for(var i=0; i < document.form2.paraCkb.length; i++){
if(document.form2.paraCkb[i].checked){
total =total +1;}
if(total > 1){
alert("Please Select only one") 
document.form2.paraCkb[j].checked = false ;
return false;}}}

//limit to 1 choice - bilingual
function bilingChkcontrol(j) {
var total=0;
for(var i=0; i < document.form3.bilingCkb.length; i++){
if(document.form3.bilingCkb[i].checked){
total =total +1;}
if(total > 1){
alert("Please Select only one") 
document.form3.bilingCkb[j].checked = false ;
return false;}}}
      

//add values of selected to check boxes and display totals
         function calcTotal()
         {
            var itemTotal = 10000;
            var items = document.querySelectorAll('input,textarea,select');
            //js variable items for all HTML elements w the input tag

            for(i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
               if (items[i].checked)//if the item is checked
               {
                  itemTotal += (items[i].value * 1);//then item total is updated to the previous total + value of checked item. Mutplied by 1 so that JS knows that it is a num
               }

               document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Your order total is:  $" + itemTotal + ".00";
               //inner HTML fills in the space between the opening and closing <p> tags with the total
            }
           
 //same as above but for the dropdown          
           for(i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
               if (items[i].selected)//if the item is checked
               {
                  itemTotal += (items[i].value * 1);//then item total is updated to the previous total + value of checked item. Mutplied by 1 so that JS knows that it is a num
               }

               document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Your order total is:  $" + itemTotal + ".00";
               //inner HTML fills in the space between the opening and closing <p> tags with the total
            }
         }

         //backwards compatibility for event listener submit button
         var calcButton = document.getElementById("calcButton"); //sButton HTML element is assign JS value of submitButton
         if (calcButton.addEventListener) //now you can add event listener
         {
            calcButton.addEventListener("click", calcTotal, false); //event is click, action is calctotal, false for bwc
         }
         else if (calcButton.attachEvent)
         {
            calcButton.attachEvent("onclick", calcTotal);   
         }
```

I'm trying to make this salary calculator. I've gotten the checkboxes to work so far. The dropdown, however, is so far a bust. I looked at the for loop that takes the values into it and found out that I needed to make another one specifically just for the dropdown. But it's still not working.

Can someone please take a look? Feel free to fork the Codepen.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// get the result of the selected option
function checkAmbulanceValue(elmt) {
  let value = elmt.options[elmt.selectedIndex].value;
  return value
}
// add option into select
function addOptionToSelect() {
  let select = document.getElementById('ambulance');
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let o = document.createElement('option');
    o.id = 'item' + i
    o.name = 'item' + i
    o.value = i * 100;
    o.innerHTML = i * 10;
    select.appendChild(o);
  }

}
addOptionToSelect();
//add values of selected to check boxes and display totals
function calcTotal() {
  let ckbValue = 0;
  let parCkbValue = 0;
  let bilingCkbValue = 0;
  let ambulanceValue = 0;
  let itemTotal = 10000;
  // cbk
  const radioButtonsCkb = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="ckb"]');
  for (const radioButton of radioButtonsCkb) {
    if (radioButton.checked) {
      ckbValue = radioButton.value;
      break;
    }
  }
  // paraCBK
  let radioButtonsPara = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="paraCkb"]');
  for (let radioButton of radioButtonsPara) {
    if (radioButton.checked) {
      parCkbValue = radioButton.value;
      break;
    }
  }
  // bilingCkbValue
  let radioButtonsBiling = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="bilingCkbValue"]');
  for (let radioButton of radioButtonsBiling) {
    if (radioButton.checked) {
      bilingCkbValue = radioButton.value;
      break;
    }
  }
  //amulance
  let select = document.getElementById('ambulance')
  ambulanceValue = checkAmbulanceValue(select);

  // total 
  itemTotal += +ckbValue;
  itemTotal += +parCkbValue;
  itemTotal += +bilingCkbValue;
  itemTotal += +ambulanceValue;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Your order total is:  $" + itemTotal + ".00";
  //inner HTML fills in the space between the opening and closing <p> tags with the total
}


//backwards compatibility for event listener submit button
let calcButton = document.getElementById("calcButton"); //sButton HTML element is assign JS value of submitButton
if (calcButton.addEventListener) //now you can add event listener
{
  calcButton.addEventListener("click", calcTotal, false); //event is click, action is calctotal, false for bwc
} else if (calcButton.attachEvent) {
  calcButton.attachEvent("onclick", calcTotal);
}
```

```css
/* The container */

.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */

.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}


/* Create a custom checkbox */

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}


/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */

.container:hover input~.checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* When the checkbox is checked, add a red background */

.container input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: red;
}


/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}


/* Show the checkmark when checked */

.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}


/* Style the checkmark/indicator */

.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.card {
  border: 5px solid #148BA6;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  background-color: #F2E394;
}

label {
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
}

body {
  background-color: #BDE3F2;
}

.button {
  background-color: red;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #8C4130;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #8C4130;
}

.buttonDiv,
.priceInfo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.priceInfo {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="card">

    <h1>Salary Calculator</h1>
    <h2>Level of Education</h2>

    <input type="radio"  name="ckb" value="2000"><label for="item1">Asso</label><br>
    <input type="radio"  name="ckb" value="4000"><label for="item2">BA</label><br>
    <input type="radio"  name="ckb" value="6000"><label for="item3">MA</label>

  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <h2>Have you worked as a paramedic?</h2>

    <input type="radio" name="paraCbk" value="5400"><label for="item1">YES</label><br>   <input type="radio"name="paraCbk" value="0"><label for="item2">NO</label><br>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <label for="edu"><h2>Are you bilingual?</h2></label>
    <input type="radio"  name="bilingCkb" value="900"><label for="item1">YES</label><br>   <input type="radio" name="bilingCkb" value="0"><label for="item2">NO</label><br>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <label for="edu"><h2>Ambulance - $25/shift</h2></label>
    <select name="ambulance" id="ambulance" onchange='checkAmbulanceValue(this)'>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <p id="total" class="priceInfo"></p>
    <div class="buttonDiv">
      <input type="button" class="button" value="Calculate Total" id="calcButton">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

check for the **checkAmbulanceValue()** function  to get the result
and **addOptionToSelect()** to put values

-edit-

- for select only one option in a set  prefere radioButton instead of checkbox
- you dont post anything so form tag is useless
- you set again and again the value after each loop, so we will see only the last result
- also you should avoid var and use let instead

look the snippet; normaly it's work

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I added a few adjustments and it's perfect.

Comment: you welcome, don't forget to mark the question as solved :)